# View page not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Today I went from my Windows server to Ubuntu. I transferred my Laravel project that I had on IIS to apache2 and installed mod rewrite. However, I can't see the pages. This is the error I get: View [pages.maintenance] not found.

This is what I added to the **000-default.config** configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</ Directory>
```

This is my htaccess (found in /var/www/html/public, (my DirectoryRoot):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </ IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond% {HTTP: Authorization}.
    RewriteRule. * - [E = HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:% {HTTP: Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder ...
    RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -D
    RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} (. +) / $
    RewriteRule ^% 1 [L, R = 301]

    # Handle Front Controller ...
    RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -D
    RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</ IfModule>
```

How come I get this? I checked the rewritten mod change and it's okay.

Comment: Notably it is complaining about the view, not the route. It seems like it found your route, found your controller, and now cannot find the specific blade file the controller wants to return. Is the resources/views/pages/maintenance.blade.php file there as expected?

Comment: The paths are right, on IIS I had no problems

Comment: Upload a pic of your three in resources/view folder. Check if URL is correct too. We need more info for help you

Comment: I think you need to check file permissions. Make sure www-data has read permission on resources/views folder

Comment: I'm positive this is about case sensitive file name